# DIY XBox360 guitar hero controller

Tags: arduino, xbox, guitar

I'm making a diy guitar controller for guitar hero on xbox 360.
As far as i could see on the web, it's not possible to build anything from stratch and just plug in the console due to MS security protocols, so DIY controllers usually have a real controller board in the middle (like this arcade controller http://hacknmod.com/hack/diy-arcade-controller-for-xbox-360/).
But some GH editions aren't playable with regular controllers, they require specificaly a guitar controller, so if I just make my custom guitar interface with a regular controller, it won't work.

Is there actually a way to interface the console without using a real controller? Or maybe sit between the actual controller and console and modify the communication to make the console think there's a guitar plugged in? In this case, would an Arduino be capable of do the job?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself, its not possible to build anything from scratch due to MS security protocols. This is the same reason that you wont be able to interface the console without a controller, the controller is used because it knows how to communicate with the security protocols. Using an arduino would not help, and i highly doubt it has the processing power that you would need even without the security protocols. Your best bet is to rip apart an actually guitar hero controller, and stuff the electronics inside of your homemade one.

Comment: Outside of the (show-stopping) security/pairing issue, I don't see why an Arduino or Beaglebone would not be a good fit. What kind of processing do you think something like this needs?

Comment: I think beaglebone could definitely do it, seeing as its a full linux machine. An arduino DUE could probably do it as well, but I'm assuming he meant the common UNO, and i dont think its fast enough to provide the amount of data needed, nor could the program to do it fit within the 30k limit